# Pixel in media query doesn't match my browser

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm adding media query into my asp.net webapp. I'm trying to make my webapp change and look different based on different type of mobile phone. I will show you the codes of my media query and the weird problem i received.

```
/*Media Query*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

#homebutton input[type=image] {
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:0%;
margin: 0px;
height:1000px;
width:50%;
}
}   

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

#homebutton input[type=image] {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:0%;
margin: 0px;
height:70px;
width:50%;
}
}
```

Based on my understanding, whenever the browser has a size between 801px - 1024px, it will run the

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

code. And when the browser has a size of 0px - 800px, it should run this line of css code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
```

However, when i try to extend my browser width to 802px, the homebutton still show the size of the homebutton in media query css 800px instead of the 1024px. Why is it so? Is my code wrong by  itself, or a misunderstanding of the media query logic on my part. I hope someone can help me on this.

Regards.

Comment: It seems to be related to the scroll bars - when removing rules that cause the scroll bars to appear [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPxJp/) behaves as it should.

Comment: is it possible for me to set a particular pixel / size for the result box in jsfiddle to ensure accuracy in the media query?

Comment: I don't think so unfortunately :( - but seeing that `window.innerWidth` alerted 801 I think it's safe to assume it's the scroll bar causing the inaccuracy of the media queries.

Comment: Check this `@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 800px) {`

Comment: @Exception  No difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try use 798px for 800px content width. You do not take into consideration the width of the scroll and border of browser.

Comment: Unfortunately even if i tested out 810px, it still follows the 800px. Only about until approximately 825px, then it follows the 1024px which i find it rather weird.

Comment: Can you give link on this site?

Comment: I'm running it on my localhost though.